# Need help centering div inside bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need your help
I'm trying to make a page with a 4 equal width bootstrap columns and a content (let's say a rectangle) inside each of the columns. However, I can't seem to find a way to position each rectangle centrally inside the columns. I need your help to find a way to position the rectangles centrally without ruining the responsive layout of the page.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="border row">

    <div class="border col-md-3"><div  class="rectangles"></div></div>

    <div class="border col-md-3"><div  class="rectangles"></div></div>

    <div class="border col-md-3"><div  class="rectangles"></div></div>

    <div class="border col-md-3"><div  class="rectangles"></div></div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not use add `text-align:center;
margin:auto;`

Comment: post the code. do you mean vertical or horizontal center?

Comment: I did but I messed up and it wasn't displayed in my question.I have edited it and it's there now. Horizontal center

Answer (score 0):

was this what you were looking for? look in full page.

```css
.rectangles1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.rectangles2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.rectangles3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.rectangles4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="border row">

    <div class="border col-sm-3">
      <div class="rectangles1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="border col-sm-3">
      <div class="rectangles2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="border col-sm-3">
      <div class="rectangles3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="border col-sm-3">
      <div class="rectangles4"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes sir, thank you for your help I'm new to web development and this was a big help

Comment: you can always change the col-sm-3 to col-xs-3 or just change the width of the rectangles since the size of the viewport is going to affect how it's display

Comment: yes sir I already have, however it said votes are recorded but not displayed since I have less than 15 rep

Comment: ah, it's okay.  you can't always make it the correct answer. teehee.  anywho if you have anymore question, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the flex-box vertical align method. And you want to add this to the parent div you want your rect centered in(I.E. the col you made for your rect)

```
.aligner{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```